# Division operator always returns an integer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am writing a Windows Forms application. Look at the second half on this code with the variable `Dim secnumber`. When I run the code and give it a value like `5` or `3` it will only round up to a whole number and I wanted it to be in decimal form. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
    'Declare variable
    Dim number As Integer

    'Extract the number from the text box
    Dim intnumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtintbox.Text)

    'Calculate to double the number
    number = intnumber * 2

    'Convert the number to display in message box
    MessageBox.Show("When the number is doubled, the result is: " & number)

    'Clear the text box
    txtintbox.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub halfbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles halfbtn.Click




    'Declare variable
    Dim secnumber As Double

    'use th number from the text box
    secnumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtintbox.Text)

    'Calculate the number by half
    secnumber = secnumber \ 2

    'Convert number to display the result in message box
    MessageBox.Show("Half of this number is: " & secnumber)

    'Clear the text box
    txtintbox.Text = ""


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question title and details. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change `secnumber = secnumber \ 2` to `secnumber = secnumber / 2`

/ is standard division
\ is integer division

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/integer-division-operator